# Not able to find setAutoFilter in HSSFWorkshhet

Tags: java, excel

i am trying to generate an excel sheet using HSSFSheet and using poi3.9 jar.
i am facing a problem where i am trying to set autofilter. but i am not able to find setAutoFilter method.
Please help me.
I am getting below error 
***The method setAutoFilter() is undefined for the type HSSFSheet***

Answer (score 1):

`setAutoFilter` needs a parameter of type `CellRangeAddress`:

```
public HSSFAutoFilter setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress range) {
```

There is no method without paramters.

I have tried it with this code:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0, 1, 0,1));
    }
}
```

and get no error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response jens. but the thing is that i not able to find even the setAutoFilter method.i am getting below error The method setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress) is undefined for the type HSSFSheet

Comment: @user2500313 Can you please add the relavant code to your question?

Comment: This is my code.   HSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.createSheet("Autofilter");
                           
                my_sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0, 5, 2, 9)); i am getting error at setAutoFilter

Comment: From wich package is `HSSFSheet` and `CellRangeAddress`?

Comment: Below are my imports.import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;